# Nexmo cannot verify user Using postman

Tags: postman, vonage

So I had followed the instruction from the documentation here: 
https://dashboard.nexmo.com/verify

but then I successfully received the sms and recieved the request_id

whenever i try to validate the message at https://api.nexmo.com/verify/check/json

it returns status of 6 and "The Nexmo platform was unable to process this message for the following reason: Request '*******************' was not found or it has been verified already."

I tried searching the request_id in the dashboard but still it cannot be found .

is it a limitation if the account is on trial?

I Have done this:
Post URL : https://api.nexmo.com/verify/json
{
    "api_key":"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "api_secret":"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "number":"xxxxxxxxx",
    "brand":"Foo"
}

post Url: https://api.nexmo.com/verify/check/json
{
    "api_key":"xxxxxxxxx",
 "api_secret":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"request_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"code":"7744"
}

Answer (score 0):

It's not a limitation for an account on trial. This error indicates that the request ID you're passing in to the second request is not the one provided in the response from https://api.nexmo.com/verify/json . Either that, or the second call, to https://api.nexmo.com/verify/check/json is being made twice (and you're only seeing the second response) but I doubt that.

Have you checked that the RequestID in your error response exactly matches what you received from the first call?

Comment: I did, it is the request Id , well i Did it on postman via curl and not in json format then I got it verified. I don't know what the problem is.